# How to show only the records from the current

Tags: mysql, sql, time, timestamp, where-clause

I want to select only the records of the current day. So I can see everyday how many visitors("bezoekers") there were.

This is the code I use:

```
Select FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%c-%d-%H') "Datum (Descending)", 
COUNT(DISTINCT address) "Bezoekers"  
FROM sensordata1  
ORDER BY 1
FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%c-%d-%H') DESC
```

What I tried :

```
Select FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%c-%d-%H') "Datum (Descending)",
COUNT(DISTINCT address) "Bezoekers"  
FROM sensordata1  
WHERE 1, DATE('Datum') = DATE(CURDATE() 
ORDER BY 1
FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time), '%Y-%c-%d-%H') DESC
```

What I want :

```
Datum         | Bezoekers
2017-4-20-15  | 31
2017-4-20-14  | 34
2017-4-20-13  | 20
2017-4-20-12  | 26
```

And I dont want for example a 2017-04-21 in there.
And if I come back the next day it needs to be from that day so your cant set a date.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and its expected result.

Comment: I already showed what i want? thats the expected result?

Comment: WHERE clause seems wrong to me... Have you tried to use HAVING...

Comment: `WHERE 1, ...` is syntactically wrong (what is the comma supposed to mean?). `WHERE DATE('Datum') = DATE(CURDATE()` is also syntactically wrong (missing closing parenthesis). Moreover you take the string `'Datum'` (single quotes are for string literals) and try to convert this string to a date. BTW: `ORDER BY 1 FROM_UnixTime...` is also syntactically wrong (remove one expression or separate the two expressions with a comma).

Comment: Expected result without having any matching sample table data makes no good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY`. If you want one result row per `FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H')`, then group by it.

```
Select
  FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H') AS "Datum (Descending)", 
  COUNT(DISTINCT address) AS "Bezoekers"  
FROM sensordata1  
GROUP BY FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H')
ORDER BY FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H') DESC;
```

Same for only the current day (which an according `WHERE` clause added):

```
Select
  FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H') AS "Datum (Descending)", 
  COUNT(DISTINCT address) AS "Bezoekers"  
FROM sensordata1  
WHERE FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%m-%d') = curdate()
GROUP BY FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H')
ORDER BY FROM_UnixTime(sensordata1.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H') DESC;
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If I add : GROUP BY FROM_UnixTime((sensordata1.time + 7200), '%Y-%c-%d-%H') it still shows the data from othere days then this day

Comment: Your query shows one result row with the total count and one of the day/hours arbitrarily chosen. But the results you want have one row per day/hour each with its with. This is what my query does. But okay, so the "What I want" is *not* what you want.

Comment: @Thorsten Maybe he wanted to add HAVING clause on "Datum (Descending" compared with Currentdate?

Comment: Ah, no, sorry, I misread. Only current day, but one row per hour. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thx this is what I needed! One more question if I want it to do with days in current month too? so I only want to show the days and number of visitors in those days from the current month?

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that you can use aliases to simplify the query.  The date logic is a bit unclear, but you seem to want yesterday's date.  You do this using a `where` clause:

```
Select from_unixtime(sd.time, '%Y-%c-%d-%H') as Datum, 
       count(distinct sd.address) as Bezoekers 
from sensordata1 sd
where sd.time >= unixtime_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day) and
      sd.time < unixtime_timestamp(curdate())
group by datum
order by datum desc
```